# How to read csv file with column containing unqouted newlines?

Tags: r, readr

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

I have this stupid csv file where someone forgot to quote the string in the
last column which may contain newlines. (The 2nd row in this example doesn’t)

```r
csv_file <- str_c(
  "a,b,c\n",
  "1,1,first\nrow\n",
  "1,1,second row\n",
  "1,1,third\nrow\n",
  collapse = ""
)
```

Trying to read the file with `read_csv()` gives rise to problems.

```r
read_csv(csv_file)
#> Warning: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details,
#> e.g.:
#>   dat <- vroom(...)
#>   problems(dat)
#> Rows: 5 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (2): a, c
#> dbl (1): b
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   a         b c         
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 1         1 first     
#> 2 row      NA <NA>      
#> 3 1         1 second row
#> 4 1         1 third     
#> 5 row      NA <NA>
```

How can one parse the file to get the expected results?

```r
tibble(
  a = c(1, 1, 1),
  b = c(1, 1, 1),
  c = c("first\nrow", "second row", "third\nrow")
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       a     b c           
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1     1     1 "first\nrow"
#> 2     1     1 "second row"
#> 3     1     1 "third\nrow"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Can the last column contain commas?

Comment: No, only text or newlines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the first column doesn't contain commas, one method would be to replace all newlines with a tab character, and then use `gsub` to replace any tab that isn't followed by another tab before the next comma. Once you have read in the data, you can easily `gsub` the tabs in the final column back into newlines:

```r
read.csv(text = gsub('\t([[:alnum:]]+),', '\n\\1,', 
                     gsub('\n', '\t', csv_file))) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(c = gsub('\t', '\n', c))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b c             
#>   <int> <int> <chr>         
#> 1     1     1 "first\nrow"  
#> 2     1     1 "second row"  
#> 3     1     1 "third\nrow\n"
```

Once you have read the data in you can easily `gsub` the tabs in the final column into newlines

---

Or alternatively with `stringr`

```
csv_file |> 
  str_replace_all(
    regex("\n(\\w+)(?=\n)", multiline = TRUE), "|\\1"
  ) |> 
  read_csv() |> 
  mutate(
    c = str_replace(c, "[|]", "\n")
  )
```

Comment: thats a great solution

Comment: @allan-cameron I've edited your answer and added another variation using basically the same approach, but instead with `stringr`. I thought that was more appropriate than adding that as another answer. I hope you agree.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `readLines()` to read in the data, build an index of fields where there are no commas and use that to concatenate the fields together.

```
txt <- readLines(textConnection(csv_file))
idx <- cumsum(grepl(",", txt))
readr::read_csv(I(tapply(txt, idx, paste, collapse = " ")), show_col_types = FALSE)

# A tibble: 3 × 3                                                                                                                                  
      a     b c         
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
1     1     1 first row 
2     1     1 second row
3     1     1 third row
```

Comment: This is really nice, but i would actually like to keep the newlines in the c column.

Comment: OK, similar to Allan's answer you can substitute a character that doesn't appear in the data instead of using a space as the collapse character, then swap that for a newline once the data is read in.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. It's not as elegant as the other proposed solutions, but I figured that the approach might come in handy for other similar type problems.

---

```
library(meltr)
```

I discovered that the `meltr` package might come in handy here since it
allows us to parse the file as is, and returns a tabular format that can be
used to fix the issues

```r
melt_csv(csv_file)
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#>      row   col data_type value     
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     
#>  1     1     1 character a         
#>  2     1     2 character b         
#>  3     1     3 character c         
#>  4     2     1 integer   1         
#>  5     2     2 integer   1         
#>  6     2     3 character first     
#>  7     3     1 character row       
#>  8     4     1 integer   1         
#>  9     4     2 integer   1         
#> 10     4     3 character second row
#> 11     5     1 integer   1         
#> 12     5     2 integer   1         
#> 13     5     3 character third     
#> 14     6     1 character row
```

First, I find the rows where there are issues

```r
(step1 <- melt_csv(csv_file) |> 
  add_row(col = 1) |>  # add dummy 
  mutate(
    bad = (col == 1) & lead(col == 1)
  ) |> 
  filter(!is.na(bad))  # remove dummy
)
#> # A tibble: 14 × 5
#>      row   col data_type value      bad  
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <lgl>
#>  1     1     1 character a          FALSE
#>  2     1     2 character b          FALSE
#>  3     1     3 character c          FALSE
#>  4     2     1 integer   1          FALSE
#>  5     2     2 integer   1          FALSE
#>  6     2     3 character first      FALSE
#>  7     3     1 character row        TRUE 
#>  8     4     1 integer   1          FALSE
#>  9     4     2 integer   1          FALSE
#> 10     4     3 character second row FALSE
#> 11     5     1 integer   1          FALSE
#> 12     5     2 integer   1          FALSE
#> 13     5     3 character third      FALSE
#> 14     6     1 character row        TRUE
```

Then I adjust `row` and `col`, and combine the strings that were split on
multiple rows.

```r
(step2 <- step1 |> 
  mutate(
    row = if_else(bad, lag(row), row),
    col = if_else(bad, lag(col), col)
  ) |> 
  group_by(row, col) |> 
  summarise(
    value = str_c(value, collapse = "\n"), .groups = "drop"
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>      row   col value       
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
#>  1     1     1 "a"         
#>  2     1     2 "b"         
#>  3     1     3 "c"         
#>  4     2     1 "1"         
#>  5     2     2 "1"         
#>  6     2     3 "first\nrow"
#>  7     4     1 "1"         
#>  8     4     2 "1"         
#>  9     4     3 "second row"
#> 10     5     1 "1"         
#> 11     5     2 "1"         
#> 12     5     3 "third\nrow"
```

The final step is used to fish out the column names from the first row, and
finally pivot the data to the “wide” format.

```r
(step3 <- step2 |> 
  mutate(
    col = value[col]
  ) |> 
  filter(row != 1) |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = col, values_from = value
  ) |> 
  select(-row)
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   a     b     c           
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>       
#> 1 1     1     "first\nrow"
#> 2 1     1     "second row"
#> 3 1     1     "third\nrow"
```